# Where is mistake in subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, url, curl, subprocess, popen

I try send file from local computer to server.

```
t= subprocess.Popen(['curl', '-T', '/home/test/Downloads/my_own.xml', 
   'http://far_away_server/'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

in stderr I see:

```
usage: curl [file] [URL]
        [file] [HTTP]     fetches a file from an 'http' URL
        [file] [HTTPS]    fetches a file from an 'https' URL
        [file] [FTP]      fetches a file from a 'ftp' URL
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Please provide exactly the command you run

Comment: @DmitryFrolov, I wrote in bash:
`>>>import subprocess
>>>t= subprocess.Popen(['curl', '-T', '/home/test/Downloads/my_own.xml', 
   'http://far_away_server/'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
>>>out, err = t.communicate()
>>>print err`

Comment: I have an error curl: `(6) Could not resolve host: far_away_server`, please give `curl --version` result.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi, you can see error message on question body.

Comment: @DmitryFrolov, because I wrote servername from my head. I cannot write the real server.))

Answer (score 0):

1. Check you have only one curl)
   for sure, write /usr/bin/curl
2. check conf.file 
   the URL(far-far server) must be there.
3. check curl-command in terminal, where all names are full.

must work...